# Android/Java : Returning postion of Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, return

I'm working on an app that register the answers each user introduces. For this purpose I have an `Array` where depending on what each user answers.

What I want to do is to get those answers and use them in another class for example in order to serialize these answers in XML.

I would like to know if there is a way of returning in a simpler way the answers. What I have now is the following code but its quite unproductive:

```
        public static String[] Respuestas = {"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};

       public static String getRespuesta1(){
            return Respuestas[0];
        }
        public static String getRespuesta2(){
            return Respuestas[1];
        }
```

And so on until get Respuesta30().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to create 30 methods for this situation, can't you simply call:

```
MyClass.Respuestas[x]; //where x is any number from 0 to 30?
```

If you really need a method, which, judging by this snippet of code you don't seem to need it, then pass the index as a parameter:

```
public static String getRespuestaByIndex(int index)
{
    return Respuestas[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an integer argument to the method `getRespuesta` that specifies the index you are interested in. Having a separate method for each element is not a good idea at all.

Answer (score 0):

The above method is an obviously better solution for your task, than having 30 functions that do the same thing. One more thing, define the array like this please:

```
public static String[] Respuestas = new String[30];
```

You may set the iterations inside the square brackets too `[]` , but I don't think that you need that.

Comment: Hi if i do that it says NullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry, corrected it. I don't know why I wrote it, but yeah, the null pointer exception comes from the fact, that there isn't any alocated space for the array.